# Map method change old array

Tags: javascript

Why map is changin' the old array `numbers` ? I don't want to change the old array, I want to edit it (`key * 2`) and put it in new array `roots`. Can someone explain what the problem is?

```js
var numbers = [{key:1,prop:"ok"}, {key:2,prop:"ok"}, {key:3,prop:"ok"}];
var roots = numbers.map(index => {
  index.key = index.key * 2
  return index
})

console.log('numbers', numbers)
console.log('roots', roots)
```

Comment: Just for you: Your "array" is a json object, not a good plain array. :-) And which Javascript framework did you use?

Comment: @reporter I think you wrote that backwards. There's no json here

Comment: okey thx, any idea to achieve that ?

Comment: @reporter dude are you serious ? **THIS IS A PLAIN JAVASCRIPT**

Comment: `map` doesn't protect you from modifying reference types. Only primitive types.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7486085/copying-array-by-value-in-javascript

Comment: `map` is not changing the old array. It is creating a new array. What is not changingn the way you have written your code, is the **objects** inside the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like there is no straight-forward way to copy a array without references.
But this works tho:

```js
var numbers = [{key:1,prop:"ok"}, {key:2,prop:"ok"}, {key:3,prop:"ok"}];
var roots = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(numbers)); 
roots.map(index => {
  index.key = index.key * 2
  return index
})

console.log('numbers', numbers)
console.log('roots', roots)
```

Comment: It works Yeah, can explain why, I didnt understand why I need to parse it sense numbers isnt a string

Comment: It's because `roots` and `numbers` point out to the same object.

Comment: If you aren't going to capture the result of the `map`, you might as well use `forEach` so you don't create a 3rd, unused array.

Comment: @4castle well I was using forEach firstly but I want to play with map a bit, btw love your comment on top

Comment: @4castle why did you remove the json tag, from question? Murat K. used `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(numbers))`.

Comment: @reporter Because the question isn't about JSON. JSON is a string. The answer only used `JSON.stringify()` to make a deep copy of the array.

Comment: Using `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify` is certainly a brute force way to clone an object, and not even necessary here.

Answer (score 2):

In your case, the simplest approach would be

```
var numbers = [{key:1,prop:"ok"}, {key:2,prop:"ok"}, {key:3,prop:"ok"}];
var roots = numbers.map(elt => ({
  key: elt.key * 2,
  prop: elt.prop
}));
```

In other words, return **new objects** from `map`.

Or if you prefer, you can destructure the parameter:

```
var roots = numbers.map(({key, prop}) => ({key: key * 2, prop}));
```

Comment: I would also rename `index` to `object`